Mixed-content issues
Is there anyone who has had the mixed-content issue, after having deployed a website. I have built an app that uses a Fastapi Backend deployed to Azure Web App and a frontend with NextJs 14 deployed to vercel. Everything is running successfully locally.  The backend and Frontend are connected via CORS. The user can authenticate successfully. The issue arises when the user sends a question (by the way the app is about chat and object detection), the request is blocked and can't reach the server. I have already tried several hacks to solve the issue. Some of the source I used to find out how to solve it is https://web.dev/articles/fixing-mixed-content.
I tried to delete external sources that I used. I also added the CSP, as explained in the attached link: I added it in the backend like this

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_csp_header(request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    # Adding Content-Security-Policy to block or upgrade mixed content
    response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "default-src 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content"
    return response

and in the frontend:
  return [
    {
      // Apply this to all routes
      source: '/(.*)',  // This applies the header to all routes in your Next.js app
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
          value: "default-src 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

in the next.config.mjs. I unfortunately, I still got the same error.
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/2CWHCIM6.png).
Please, find below the detailed error from the Chrome console. Below, I tried to connect to the backend deployed to azure (the same backend as before) using the nextJs frontend running locally.
detailed error from chrome console

Please share the error in text format

Open Chrome DevTools (F12) on your site and go to the Console tab. Look specifically for warnings or errors regarding mixed content. These errors will indicate which HTTP resources are being loaded on the HTTPS page.


If any HTTP URLs are listed, try accessing those URLs directly over HTTPS in the browser. If they work, manually update the code and replace with https://.

from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["https://your-vercel-domain.com"],
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
    allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
)


CSP header you've added should help block or upgrade mixed content.

try this CSP rule - response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "default-src 'self' https:; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content"  - This cmd allows the content from the site and secure sources
Logs:
[INFO] Starting application...
[INFO] Connection to FastAPI backend established successfully via HTTPS.
[INFO] WebSocket connection initialized with Azure WebPubSub via wss://your-webpubsub-endpoint.
[INFO] Chat message sent successfully to backend: "Hello!"
[INFO] Object detection request sent to backend.
[INFO] Received response from backend for object detection.
[INFO] CSP: All resources loaded securely.
[INFO] All external resources loaded over HTTPS.

Network table:


I tried this but it didn't work. It seems like the issue comes the bad configuration of my azure web app, I guess. Because: 1. the backend is loaded securely with https://backend.azurewebsites.net. 2 I can autehtenticate easily the user. 3. But the when I send a request to the backend endpoint chat, https://backend.azurewebsites.net/chat, it passes Https to http://backend.azurewebsites.net/chat. That's where the issue is coming. I tried to set " HTTPS Only" on in azure web app at settings>configuration, but it still gives the same issue.

clear all your cookies or else try in another browser.
